# Best usage for MongoDB Aggregate request

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I would like to highlight a list of _id documents (with a limit) ranked in descending order (via their timestamp) based on a list of ObjectId.

Corresponding to this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $match: { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("X"), ObjectId("Y") ] } } }, { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$_id" } }, { $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 100 } ] )
```

Knowing that the list from the loop may contain way more than 1000 ObjectId (in $in array), do you think my solution is viable? Is not there a faster and less resource intensive way?

Best Regards.

Comment: Index the `timestamp` field, use a find query: `db.collection.find({"_id":{$in:input}}).sort({"timestamp":-1}).limit(100);`, this still wouldn't affect the arguments to the `$in` operator, you could try setting up different shards for a parallel distributed search, or fire `n` number of queries by splitting up the input array and do a union of results on the client side.

Comment: Per @BatScream's comment you should use a simpler `find()` query instead of the aggregation framework (where you are doing unnecessary processing like grouping by an `_id` which is already unique). The suggested index would be `{ _id: 1, timestamp: -1}`, since you are searching by `_id` and would like results sorted in descending timestamp order. For more info on indexing, [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) is a helpful read.